# What is the importance of Zorn's lemma in Tychonoff theorem proof?

Tags: general-topology, set-theory

I read that Tychonoff's theorem states that given a family of topological spaces $\{(X_i,\tau_i),i \in I\}$, the product topology $(X,\tau)=\prod_{i \in I}(X_i,\tau_i)$ is compact iff each $(X_i,\tau_i)$ is compact.

The proof states that given any family $\mathcal{F}$ of closed subsets of $X$ with the finite intersection property, there is a maximal family $\mathcal{H}$ that contains $\mathcal{F}$ and which also has the finite intersection property. The existence of $\mathcal{H}$ is shown using Zorn's lemma.

The proof goes on to show that $\bigcap_{H \in \mathcal{H}}\bar{H} \neq \emptyset \implies \bigcap_{F \in \mathcal{F}}F \neq \emptyset$, from which the theorem follows. I won't go into the details, but the proof took a 'slice' from each $H \in \mathcal{H}$, using a projection function $p_i$, so that $p_i(H) \in X_i$. Since each $p_i(H)$ has the finite intersection property for $i \in I$, and $X_i$ is compact, we can get the intersection $x_i$ of all $p_i(H)$, and form $x=\prod_{i\in I}x_i \in X$. It follows that with $x$, we have $\bigcap_{H \in \mathcal{H}}\bar{H} \neq \emptyset$

I think am missing a step,  but what is the importance of having to use Zorn's lemma to get a maximal $\mathcal{H}$ and show that $\bigcap_{H \in \mathcal{H}}\bar{H} \neq \emptyset$. Since $\mathcal{F}$ already has the finite intersection property, can we not use any arbitrary $\mathcal{F}$?

Comment: The axiom of choice could be directly used to simultaneously choose an element $x_i$ from each $\bigcap_{F\in\mathcal F} p_i(F)$. This step is somehow traded off for the usage of Zorn lemma.

Comment: Are there still people who prove Tychonoff without using ultrafilters ?

Comment: @Max: I mean, $\mathcal{H}$ here is an ultrafilter.  This is the ultrafilter proof just without saying the word "ultrafilter".

Comment: @EricWofsey : after thinking about it, I agree that it is the ultrafilter proof; I was surprised at first by freakish's answer that says that the full proof was too long for the answer, so I didn't look at the specifics of the proof. If mentioning ultrafilters actually shortens it, then my question is still relevant I think.

Comment: Right, if you develop the theory of convergence of (ultra)filters first, then that greatly shortens the proof, because a big chunk of the work of the proof is hidden in that theory.

Comment: @Max You could also prove Alexander's subbase lemma using Zorn, and then Tychonoff is a relatively easy consequence. Or use nets and universal nets (as I did [here](http://at.yorku.ca/p/a/c/a/13.pdf)), e.g. But Tychonoff implies AC (see [here](http://at.yorku.ca/p/a/c/a/01.htm)) or Zorn too, equivalently, so we cannot avoid it. Tychonoff himself did his proof using points of complete accumulation (no FIP families or ultradilters at all) and only for $[0,1]^I$ originally.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma : yes I know, but Alexander's lemma is very technical and one needs imagination to find it - where the proof with ultrafilter is extremely natural and most importantly extremely easy. + it allows to distinguish between various flavors of AC : with Alexander's lemma you use Zorn so you're done for in all situations, with ultrafilters if you work with Hausdorff spaces, you only need a weaker variant of AC, which is a distinction the proof with Alexander's lemma can't make.

Comment: (cont.) a friend of mine originally didn't believe how easy ultrafilters were so in under 10 min I explained to him how they related to topology and proved Tychonoff's theorem with them. The proof of Alexander's lemma I remember laster a good 40min in class (@EricWofsey this also answers your point about "the theory of convergence of ultrafilters")

Comment: @Max but the subbase lemma is also useful for ordered spaces and hyperspaces. It’s worth to know it.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma : Didn't know about those, so I can't argue - you probably know more about this stuff than I do ! I still think that if your goal is explicitly to prove Tychonoff's theorem, the quickest, clearest, most powerful and efficient way is through ultrafilters.

Comment: In the set-theoretic axiom system  ZF there are many statements that have been shown to be equivalent to AC (Axiom of Choice) including Zorn's Lemma, the Teichmuller-Tukey Lemma, the Tychonoff Theorem, and the assertion that any filter on a set  $S$ can be extended to an ultafilter on $S$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet the ultrafilter theorem is equivalent to Tychonoff’s theorem for compact *Hausdorff* spaces and is strictly weaker than full AC.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma . Thanx for the correction on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the step you are missing is that the proof you have, very lightly concludes that $\bigcap\overline{H}\neq\emptyset$. Which should be understood as $x\in\bigcap\overline{H}$. But why? This is unclear and to prove that **you need $\mathcal{H}$ to be maximal**.

First I will show you an example when it fails if $\mathcal{H}$ is not maximal. Consider $X_1=X_2=\{0,1\}$ with discrete topology. Then $X=X_1\times X_2$ has four elements. Let $\mathcal{H}=\{K\}$ consist of a single closed subset $K=\{(0,0),(1,1)\}$. Obviously $\mathcal{H}$ has FIP (Finite Intersection Property). But $\mathcal{H}$ is not maximal since we can extend it with for example $\{(1,1)\}$ and maintain FIP.

Now lets construct $x$. Apply projection $\pi_1$ to $\mathcal{H}$ to get $\pi_1(K)=\{0,1\}$. So we have two choices for $x_1$. Since the choice is arbitrary then pick $x_1=0$. Now apply $\pi_2$ to $\mathcal{H}$ to get $\pi_2(K)=\{0,1\}$ as well. And again the choice of $x_2$ is arbitrary, so lets take $x_2=1$ this time. So we end up with $x=(0,1)$ which doesn't belong to $K$ and therefore it doesn't belong to $\bigcap_{H\in\mathcal{H}}\overline{H}$.

One way to fix that situation is too somehow pick $x_\alpha$ in a smart way. But there doesn't seem to be a way to do that in general. It turns out that it is easier to enlarge $\mathcal{H}$ as much as we can so that any choice of $x_\alpha$ becomes valid.

So as you can see the assumption about $\mathcal{H}$ being maximal is crucial. That's why we can't apply the reasoning to $\mathcal{F}$, because it might not be big enough. Actually $\mathcal{F}$ hardly ever is maximal because it contains closed subsets only.

Anyway the full proof is a bit too long for Math StackExchange so please have a look at details here:

https://www.math.arizona.edu/files/grad/workshops/integration/projects/tychonoff.pdf

Notice that the statement "$x\in\overline{H}$ for each $H$" is not trivial at all. And I'm surprised that whoever wrote the proof you have, treated it as obvious.

Comment: Okay thanks, but just a short question. Does $\mathcal{H}$ being maximal imply that it can 'take' in all possible combinations of inverse projections $x_i$ from the $X_i$? (where the inverse projections are used in constructing $x$)

Comment: @LinkL yes, that is a valid way of thinking about it. Even better then mine so I've included it in the answer.

Comment: @freakish __|\\__ thank you sir